# css, change other element's background when hovering over a particular element?

Tags: css, hover, css-selectors

Okay first the code..

```
<td class="btnSaveBooking">
    <div class="btnSaveBookingContainder">
        <div id="save">
            <span class="btnImage"></span><span class="btnsavebookingspan">
                <input type="submit" style="color:White;background-color:#6086AC;border-color:White;border-width:2px;border-style:Solid;font-family:Verdana;font-size:10pt;font-weight:bold;" id="btnSaveBooking" value="" name="btnSaveBooking">
                (F8)</span></div>
    </div>![enter image description here][1]
</td>
```

The images

Normal   [image]
OnMouseOver *at the button*    [image]
OnMouseOver *at the imaage*   [image]

As you can see, when user hovers *exactly over the image, then only* is the background of image changing, what I want is, when user even hovers over this button, the image should change.

Here's the css

```
.btnSaveBooking {
   border-top: 1px solid #7abbde;
    background: #1776a6;
   background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#7ec5e8), to(#1776a6));
   background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #7ec5e8, #1776a6);
   background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #7ec5e8, #1776a6);
   background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #7ec5e8, #1776a6);
   background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #7ec5e8, #1776a6);
   padding: 2px 20px 3px 4px;
   -webkit-border-radius: 11px;
   -moz-border-radius: 11px;
   border-radius: 11px;
   -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,1) 0 1px 0;
   -moz-box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,1) 0 1px 0;
   box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,1) 0 1px 0;
   text-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,.4) 0 1px 0;
   color: #f7f7f7;
   font-size: 17px;
   font-family: Georgia, Serif;
   text-decoration: none;
   vertical-align: middle;
   }
.btnSaveBooking:hover {
   border-top-color: #000000;
   background: #7288c9;
   color: #ffffff;
   }
.btnSaveBooking:active {
   border-top-color: #3c637d;
   background: #3c637d;
   }

#save .btnImage
{
    background: url("../images/save.png") no-repeat scroll 2px 5px transparent !important;
    border-color: transparent !important;
    height: 24px;
    position: relative;
    width: 28px;
    margin: 1px 1px 1px 10px;
    padding: 4px 2px 0 20px;
}

#save .btnImage:hover
{
    background: url("../images/saveN.png") no-repeat scroll 2px 5px transparent !important;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to change where the text ':hover' appears in your rule. As it stands, the img itself needs to be hovered. Change the rule so that when it's parent is hovered it changes.

I.e

```
#save .btnImage:hover
```

becomes

```
.btnSaveBooking:hover .btnSaveBookingContainder .btnImage
```

This way, the image changes as the button's background does. The answer already given gives you a 'two-stage' approach to the change.

Comment: No it won't work. By applying `.btnSaveBooking:hover .btnSaveBookingContainder .btnImage` the background of `btnSaveBooking` div is changed, not the image of the span. It thus creates a new image when hovering, that is one other than the one contained in span

Comment: @Razort4x - false. It's the input element that has the white border. There's one image both before and during hover.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
.btnSaveBookingContainder:hover .btnImage
{
    background: url("../images/saveN.png") no-repeat scroll 2px 5px transparent !important;
    cursor:pointer;
    width:28px;
    height:31px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

remove the `#save .btnImage:hover` css from your existing css, and try with the following style format,

```
.btnSaveBooking:hover{
  /* over border, background & text color */
}
.btnSaveBooking:active
{
  /* active border, background & text color */
}

.btnSaveBooking:hover #save .btnImage{
  /* provide your hover image style */
}
.btnSaveBooking:active #save .btnImage{
  /* provide your active image style */
}
```